# Grouping similar jQuery functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to group the two very similar jQuery functions into just one. Any idea?

**HTML:**

```
<input id="progress" type="text" class="spinner-input form-control" maxlength="3" readonly value="<?php echo $progreso['progress'] ?>">
<div class="spinner-buttons input-group-btn btn-group-vertical">                   
    <button id="plus" type="button" class="btn spinner-up btn-xs btn-info">                       
        <i class="icon-angle-up"></i>                    
    </button>                     
    <button id="minus" type="button" class="btn spinner-down btn-xs btn-info">                        
        <i class="icon-angle-down"></i>                     
    </button>                  
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).on('click', '#plus', function(e){
    var progress = parseInt( $('#progress').val() ) + 5;
    if ( progress <= 100 ) {
        $('#progress').val( progress );
    }
    else{
        $('#progress').val( 100 );  
    };
});

$(document).on('click', '#minus', function(e){
    var progress = parseInt( $('#progress').val() ) - 5;
    if ( progress >= 0 ) {
        $('#progress').val( progress );
    }
    else{
        $('#progress').val( 0 );    
    };
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First step would be to extract a function that updates the input:

```
function modifyProgress(delta) {
  var element = $('#progress');
  var progress = +element.val() + delta;
  element.val( isNaN(progress) ? 0 : progress < 0 ? 0 : progress > 100 ? 100 : progress;
);
}
```

BTW, never ever use `parseInt` with out its second parameter (radix). Some browsers interpret numbers starting with a leading `0` (zero) as octal, so that an input of `"09"` throws an error and `"010"` to returns `8`. Better is to use the [unary plus operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#-_.28Unary_Plus.29).

This simplifies the event handler:

```
$(document).on('click', '#plus, #minus', function(e){
   modifyProgress(5 * (this.id === "plus" ? 1 : -1));
})
```

EDIT: You should consider storing your progress value somewhere other inside the `input` such as a data model (see [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)). Keeping data/logic separate from the GUI is always a good thing. It also avoids needing to re-parse the number every time. And you can "hide" the checking of overflow or underflow inside the model.

Answer (score 2):

Introduce a third function that both of the first two call.

```
function adjustSpinner(value, amount) {
    var progress = parseInt(value,10) + amount;
    if (progress > 100) return 100;
    if (progress < 0) return 0;
    return progress;
}

$(document).on('click', '#plus', function(e){
    $('#progress').val(adjustSpinner($('#progress').val(), 5));
});

$(document).on('click', '#minus', function(e){
    $('#progress').val(adjustSpinner($('#progress').val(), -5));
});
```

Comment: You forgot converting `$('#progress').val()` to a number. This will just lead to string concatenation.

Comment: Good point. Got ahead of myself. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You could define one function:

```
function plus_or_minus(event)
{
    var isPlus = $(this).id === '#plus';

    var progress = parseInt($('#progress').val(), 10); 

    if(isPlus)
        progress += 5;
    else
        progress -= 5;

    if(progress > 100)
        progress = 100;
    else if(progress < 0)
        progress = 0;

    $('#progress').val(progress);
}


// And then bind
$(document).on('click', '#plus', plus_or_minus);
$(document).on('click', '#minus', plus_or_minus);
```

When condensing your code, try to abstract the common parts out to one function - with a simple check against the target element's ID, we can figure out whether to add or subtract. Next, we check `progress`'s value against 100 and 0 to keep it in bounds either way. Finally, apply the value to the `#progress` element.

Keep in mind that it's a good idea to always pass a base parameter to `parseInt` - usually the default will be base 10, but there are no promises made when it comes to dealing with as many browsers as there are out there.

PS I haven't tested this, the only part I'm iffy on is the `var isPlus = ...` as I haven't done jQuery in a while. If that fails to work, maybe try `var isPlus = $(this) == $('#plus')`

PPS As a bonus, I think jQuery can accept multiple targets for a single `on` command - research the docs and see if you can bind the function to both elements at the same time

Comment: Checking the id would be `id.this === "plus"` (without jQuery) or `$(this).attr("id") === "plus"` (with jQuery). `$(this) == $('#plus')` just tries to compare two jQuery objects that may both point to the same element, but they still be two different objects and thus never equal.

Comment: @RoToRa thanks - I thought maybe the two would be "loosely equal" with the `==`